# She’s too vain to wear glasses. (Why a person who is vain can't wear glasses?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She’s too vain to wear glasses.

I saw this sentence in a dictionary. Why a person who is vain can't wear glasses?

Comment: She can wear glasses, but she chooses not to because she is vain about her appearance. She thinks she has a pretty or beautiful face, and believes that glasses would hide that from people who see her. Note: there are men like that too.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I recommend you should answer this question.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of "vain"?  If you do, then I suspect that there is no English learning problem, but a cultural misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the adjective 'vain' about a person in more than one way:

Generally: we can just say that a person 'is vain' with no further words if we mean they are vain in general (they have a high opinion of themselves). We are not surprised to find that they consider themselves more beautiful, clever, etc than other people. Also, we can discuss a person's vanity about one aspect of themselves, e.g. their appearance. If a person was vain about their face, they might not wish to wear glasses because they would partly hide it from onlookers.

She can wear glasses, but she chooses not to because she is vain about her appearance. She thinks she has a pretty or beautiful face, and believes that glasses would hide that from people who see her. Note: there are men like that too.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't mean that she *cannot* wear glasses, but that she *won't* wear glasses.

She believes wearing glasses will make her less beautiful, and because she is vain, looking beautiful is more important to her than being able to see properly, so she refuses to wear them.